# intel-sdw message in dmesg

Tags: intel, dmesg

I've a Acer Swift 3 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Recently I started getting the following message continuously in my `dmesg`:

```
[ 1850.107303] sdw_cdns_irq: 163616 callbacks suppressed
[ 1850.107307] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 1850.107334] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
```

Does anyone know what it means?

Noticed that this errors comes with  linux kernel 5.11 if I downgrade to 5.9 the messge is not shown. I have upgraded to linux kernel 5.13.12-051312-generic the error is not showing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same messages. In addition to a high cpu usage, do you have also this problem?

I managed to solve this by unloading the alsa modules.

```
sudo alsa unload
```

however, you will lose the sound.

ref:  [irq/185-AudioDS using more than 60% of the CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361496/irq-185-audiods-using-more-than-60-of-the-cpu)

I will upgrade to a newer kernel to see if it also works for me.