# irq/185-AudioDS using more than 60% of the CPU

Tags: cpu-load

i just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with kernel 5.11.0-27-generic on a Acer Swift 3 SF314 and i have a process called irq/185-AudioDS that uses more than 60% of the CPU all the time.

[top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLXQV.png)

In addition, the dmesg output has this messages:

```
[ 2430.491653] sdw_cdns_irq: 137830 callbacks suppressed
[ 2430.491658] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491683] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491736] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491739] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491797] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491801] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491859] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491862] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491920] intel-sdw intel-sdw.0: Bus clash for control word
[ 2430.491924] intel-sdw intel-sdw.1: Bus clash for control word
```

What can i do? Thanks

**Edit**

To avoid this issue, however it's not the best thing to do because you will lose the audio, is to unload all the alsa modules:

```
sudo alsa unload
```

Comment: What can you do about what? Does something not work? Are you getting an error? Did you make any effort to find out what irq/185-AudioDS is?

Comment: I don't know nothing about it, i google it and I didn't find any information about it, just someone that have the same issue without any reply. I didn't get an error, however the cpu is always at 60% more or less

Comment: Funny I also googled it and found many references.

Comment: 1) Try disabling the software that uses that card, and see if the interrupts decrease. 2) Try removing that card from the system, and unloading the driver, and see if there's improvement. 3) move that card to another slot and see if that helps. 4) check for updated drivers or patches for the software.

Comment: @darth_epoxy thanks a lot. I did alsa unload and the messages disappeared and also the high CPU usage. Could be problem related to the driver?

Comment: i am also facing the same issue after i upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 on my acer swift 3 laptop. This process named: irq/185-AudioDS is constantly using about 8% CPU. Its a intel 4core/8thread cpu. this issue was not there on previous version of ubuntu.

Comment: there seems to be a bug report about this, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1943392  and it should be fixed in next version of ubuntu